# Sorting a list is giving out the wrong answer

Tags: python, sorting

I'm doing this to sort a list with high scores:

```
with open("scores.csv", "r") as x:
    reader = csv.DictReader(x)
    scores = []  # Makes an empty listto store the scores
    for row in reader:
        scores.append([row["Name"], row["Score"]])
    # Sorts the list by score
    scores.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

But this is the output:

```
[['AnotherUser', '3'], ['James', '15'], ['James', '13'], ['User2', '12'], ['James', '0']]
```

Obviously, the result should be this:

```
[['James', '15'], ['James', '13'], ['User2', '12'], ['AnotherUser', '3'], ['James', '0']]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your key is composed of strings. Edit: Ok, U9-Forward was faster. :) Edit2: Oh and btw: This is not an array! `scores` is a `list`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last line should be:

```
scores.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Instead of:

```
scores.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Because string comparison is very off, you know :-)

So compare the integers.

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake on my end :p

Comment: @UnicornsOnLSD YW: It's okay, happy to help :D, :-), 